# Разбитие строки на слова по знакам препинания

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, split

Как разбить строку на отдельные слова, игнорируя знаки препинания?

Строка может содержать слова, целые числа, числа с плавающей точкой.

Например: `"I like you 100 times, and you?  I'm not sure about number 1.2345."`

Должно быть: `[I, like, you, 100, times, and, you, I, m, not, sure, about, number, 1.2345]`.

Я пробовал так:

```
String[] words = s.split("[\\p{P} \\t\\n\\r]");
```

Проблема в том, что числа с плавающей точкой тоже разбиваются через точку, а мне этого не нужно.

Comment: а как вы предлагаете различать точку в конце предложения от точки в числе с плавающей запятой?

Comment: Мне кажется, тут надо исходить из того, что точка, за которой следует число или буква - или вообще не пустое место - надо оставить в слове. `String[] words = s.split("[\\p{P} \\t\\n\\r&&[^.]]+|\\.(?!\\S)");` Но остается пустой элемент в конце.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такой код:

```
String s = "I like you 100 times, and you? I'm not sure about number 1.2345.";
String[] parts = (s + " ").split("\\p{P}?[ \\t\\n\\r]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

выдаёт

> [I, like, you, 100, times, and, you, I'm, not, sure, about, number, 1.2345]

Трюк в том, что мы считаем точку концом предложения только если после неё есть пробел. И делаем знак препинания необязательным. Для того, чтобы финальная точка ловилась, дописываем ещё пробел в конец строки.